# Reassigning C macro to its previous value?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Before including a header file, I want to change a macro, like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO STATE_0

...

#undef MY_MACRO
#define MY_MACRO STATE_1
#include "my_header.h"
```

However, I'd like to change the macro back to its previous value after including the header, like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO STATE_0

...

#undef MY_MACRO
#define MY_MACRO STATE_1
#include "my_header.h"

#define MY_MACRO [previous value] // reassigns MY_MACRO to STATE_0
```

`MY_MACRO` can store one of several (so far, just two) states.

I have two possible solutions, but none of them are as simple as I want. The first one is to create a temporary macro storing the previous value of `MY_MACRO`. However, using `#define OLD_MACRO MY_MACRO` does not work, since `OLD_MACRO` will be replaced by `MY_MACRO`, so it will change when `MY_MACRO` changes. What I instead did, was to define `OLD_MACRO` like this:

```
#if MY_MACRO == STATE_0
#define OLD_MACRO STATE_0
#elif MY_MACRO == STATE_1
#define OLD_MACRO STATE_1
#else
#error Invalid state
#endif
```

After including the header, I can write this:

```
#if OLD_MACRO == STATE_0
#define MY_MACRO STATE_0
#elif OLD_MACRO == STATE_1
#define MY_MACRO STATE_1
#else
#error Invalid state
#endif

#undef OLD_MACRO
```

This approach requires a lot of code, and if I ever need more possible states for `MY_MACRO`, I have to add code in two additional places. I could use a constant variable rather than a macro to represent `OLD_MACRO` and redefine `MY_MACRO` as that variable, but then `MY_MACRO` would have to be evaluated at run-time since it's an alias for a variable, which I don't want. Another possible better solution was to use another macro in `my_header.h` if it exists, but use the default macro if it doesn't. In that case, `my_header.h` would look something like this:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO
#define MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO MY_MACRO
#endif
```

In that case, I would use `MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO` rather than `MY_MACRO` in `my_header.h`, and the source file including `my_header.h` would look like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO STATE_0

...

#define MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO STATE_1
#include "my_header.h"
#undef MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO
```

However, `MY_MACRO` is used in a lot of different files, and I think it's a little weird and inconsistent to use another macro in one specific file because of how it's included somewhere else. Is there a better way?

Comment: In standard C I don't see any alternative to your "lot of code". If you are under `gcc` or `clang` you can take a look to [Push/Pop Macro Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html)

Comment: @DavidRanieri I've seen those, but I haven't thought about them. Thanks a lot, I might use that :)

Comment: Have you considered the command like flag `-D` to define your "unsettled" macro at build time? If you want to make things interesting, you could have 'parallel' versions of the header files and use the `-I` to add to the standard search path(s) for header files... No end of possibilities...

Comment: (a) In general, you should avoid complicated use of the preprocessor. That is not what it is for. (b) Questions like this may be [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You should explain the context of this problem and what motivated you to seek this solution. Given that information, people may have advice about better approaches.

Comment: (c) If only one level of saved value is needed, an approach may be to use `#define MY_MACRO` `MY_MACRO_MAIN_VALUE`, then define `MY_MACRO_MAIN_VALUE` to whatever you want, then use `#undef MY_MACRO` and `#define MY_MACRO STATE_1` before including a header and `#undef MY_MACRO` and `#define MY_MACRO MY_MACRO_MAIN_VALUE` after the include.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That sounds very interesting. It would be kind of like my second approach (the one with ```MY_HEADER_MY_MACRO```), except the "fake" macro is used in all files rather than just one. I'll think about it :)